# Can I automatically update Shopware plugins from store.shopware.com taking care of the compatibility?

Tags: composer-php, shopware6

We are managing our Shopware 6 plugins via composer.

TL;DR

In case you don't manage the store via composer, I believe the extension store's version compatibility is taken into account.

But when using composer, I think this valuable information is not used?

---

So our project' `composer.json` contains for example:

```
"store.shopware.com/froshproductcompare": "^1.2",
```

I am wondering if I could safely change this to

```
"store.shopware.com/froshproductcompare": "*",
```

to get the recent version compatible with the current core.

The `composer.json` of the plugin contains:

```
    "require": {
        "shopware/core": "^6.4",
        "shopware/storefront": "^6.4"
    },
```

While the information in the store contains a more realistic constraint:

[image: constraint in the store, 1.2.3 only until 6.4.20]

Can this compatibility info from the store be used in composer updates in any way or do we have to manually check the compatibility with the store info?

Are there any plans to improve this?

Comment: How do you define "safely"? Why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: I define it as taking the Shopware core versions a plugin was released for (i.e. the infos in the store) into account.

Answer (score 2):

```
"store.shopware.com/froshproductcompare": "*",
```

This would sooner or later end up with a version conflict. The asterisk will match the latest version of the plugin and if their requirement mismatches with the local `shopware/core` version, I don't it can be resolved automatically. It just sees two dependencies clashing, how would it know that one takes priority?

> Can this compatibility info from the store be used in composer updates in any way or do we have to manually check the compatibility with the store info?
>
> Are there any plans to improve this?

If the plugin developer doesn't keep the version constraints in sync with what they require in the store, that's not good practice on their part. There's not a whole lot to improve in that regard, other than maybe enforcing it more strictly, which retroactively likely wouldn't be possible anyways.

Comment: I think one way would be to pull the compatibility info from the composer.json and use in the store - currently it's possible to add compatibility for a new version without uploading a new package... ️

Comment: Yes, that could be one way going forward but it would have to communicated prominently, as it probably is a bad habit for many plugin devs to not so regularly update the version constraints in the `composer.json`.